# Problem creating project with Cross GCC in Eclipse

Tags: fedora, c++, eclipse

I am new to Linux and Eclipse world. I am using Kepler Eclipse on Fedora 19 for C/C++ development. It does not allow me to create Project with Cross GCC ToolChain. Whenever I select Cross GCC, Finish button get disabled.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! As it stands, your question is not clear. Perhaps you could include a screenshot (upload it to a site like imgur.com) to illustrate what is going on?

Comment: You'll get better help with this on S.O. I think (voted to move).

Comment: The screenshot of the settings and/or the important parts of the configuration file.

Comment: @goldilocks why? This is not a programming question, there is no code involved, it is about using a particular program. If anything, it should be on SU, not SO.

Comment: Do you have a GCC cross-compiler toolchain installed?

Comment: @goldilocks OK, fair enough. Still think that it would be better suited to SU but I guess that's because I am much more active there than on SO.

Comment: @cjm right and not just that - it has to be somewhere Eclipse is able to find it.